# My cats drink from our swimming pool

Tags: cats, dogs, health, safety, swimming

My cats (three kittens) like to drink from our swimming pool, which is filled with a lot of chlorine. This has been going on for a a pretty long time, and even though I provide a huge bowl of fresh water they do not want to drink it. Three of my kittens have been drinking from the pool, and after a while they stopped eating. Once they stopped eating they started vomiting water out of their mouths and they are starting to get skinny. Please help, what should I do?

Comment: if your kittens do not eat and drink by now you need to take them to the vet,dehydration is a real danger to kittens and they need immediate care by a vet.

Comment: Get to the vet IMMEDIATELY, and buy a pool cover on your way home.

Comment: You need to bring your cats to the vet before they become too skinny and dehydrated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take your kittens to the vet. Dehydration is very dangerous to kittens and it might be fatal very quickly, if not treated in time.

The best thing is to avoid chlorine in a swimming pool where animals are likely to drink water. There are better and less harmful chemicals you can use, like hydrogen peroxide.

And there is the obvious solution of keeping the cats away from the pool.

Other animals will drink from your swimming pool too, so from an environmental point of view it is best to avoid chlorine in your swimming pool.

Your water supplier does probably add some chlorine to the water, so you can most likely reduce the amount of chlorine you add to the swimming pool.

There are several ways to disinfect your swimming pool, your options are: ultraviolet sterilizer, which uses light to kill bacteria and viruses; and ozone generator, which uses ozone to disinfect and remove color and odors from the water. Both of them are harmless to animals and people if used as recommended.

Hydrogen peroxide is an agressive oxidizer that removes color, odors and disinfects the water. It gets neutralized in a few hours (it gets broken down to clean water and oxygen).